# For sockets, which side does the majority of the work?

Tags: c, sockets

For sockets, which side does the majority of the work?

I've been given this question to answer and don't really understand what it means. I've browsed through the web to find answers. However, nothing. So can somebody guide me to what it's actually asking? What it means?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing the question means *among the client and the host of a socket connection, who works more?* The answer is "it depends", though. The host, on most programs, but that doesn't say much

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework question? If you're talking about host/server then it really depends, is there any other context, like a certain model?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense without more context. I can't even guess at what it's asking.

Comment: @Cramer Yes. You are correct, it's a homework question. That's the actual question.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn I thought that's what it was kind of implying but was not sure if I assumed right

Comment: Presumably, your teacher either went over sockets in class, or the textbook described sockets in detail.  Either way, you should already know which side does the most work.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You are misunderstanding my question if that's how you feel, thanks.

Comment: OK, you need to ask your teacher, then.  We're not in the business of trying to decipher vague questions from teachers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I come here for opinions on what other people think of this before I go to my instructor. But with you as a moderator, and seeming to be one of the few to see this as a bad question, then maybe I shall look elsewhere.

Comment: We can't read your instructor's mind, and without further information from you about the context, we can't figure out the question.  Ask your instructor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Who's in charge of you because your moderation skills are lacking. I see you edited your comment when you talked poorly of an instructor. You know nothing of my instructor, therefore how dare you say he's not a good instructor. Again, who's your supervisor, else I'll be happy to do my own research.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Client should know the details of the server it connects to. The `connect` call is instantaneous.

But on the other hand the server should be continuously listening to a port for any incoming connections in the `accept` call.

So technically a server would take more of the processor time.

Once the connection is established the client and server pretty much has the same work in terms of sending and receiving messages.

Comment: I know the question was little unclear. But was anything wrong with this answer. Downvoters, add reason for it